# JCombobox dropdown visibility issue?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, miglayout, z-order

I have a root panel (2 rows, 1 column) which has panel P and a label L in it. P has a JComboBox B in it. Whenever I click on B, the resulting dropdown shows-up behind L. How do I fix this? I played around with all sorts of setComponentZOrder() but I could not fix this. What should I do?

Comment: I am using MigLayout("wrap 1") on the root panel

Comment: I never see that (except `OverlayLayout`), which `LayoutManager` is used for ? or by mixing `ATW Components` with `Swing JComponents`

Comment: You were right I had mixed in a awt.Label instead of using swing.JLabel. Switching to latter, fixed my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @mKorbel: This happens even when combining `JFrame.getRootPane()` with Swing components as I've just experienced. Btw., I can see you're even more active than you used to be on "builder".

Comment: @maaartinus I can't believe ...., :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix heavyweight components (e.g. Label) with lightweight components (e.g. JLabel).

If you use Swing always use lightweight components starting with a J.

Answer (score 1):

use `combobox.setOpaque(true)`

I found this [here](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6768307).